# How to get all words from spacy vocab?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I need all the words from Spacy vocab. Suppose, I initialize my spacy model as

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

How do I get the text of words from `nlp.vocab`?

Comment: What do you need exactly?spacy's vocabulary dict for English?

Comment: yes. I am trying to use the nlp.vocab without explicitly downloading it from a URL. Then, use it as a corpus for spell correction(symspell).

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523161/spacy-word-in-vocabulary

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can get it as a list like this:

```
list(nlp.vocab.strings)
```

Answer (score 8):

As of spaCy v3.0, we need to run

`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

and then e.g.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
words = set(nlp.vocab.strings)
word = 'would'
print(f"Is '{word}' an English word: {word in words}")  # True
```