# spaCy: Word in vocabulary

Tags: spacy, vocabulary

I try to do typo correction with spaCy, and for that I need to know if a word exists in the vocab or not. If not, the idea is to split the word in two until all segments do exist. As example, "ofthe" does not exist, "of" and "the" do. So I first need to know if a word exists in the vocab. That's where the problems start. I try:

```
for token in nlp("apple"):
    print(token.lemma_, token.lemma, token.is_oov, "apple" in nlp.vocab)
apple 8566208034543834098 True True

for token in nlp("andshy"):
    print(token.lemma_, token.lemma, token.is_oov, "andshy" in nlp.vocab)
andshy 4682930577439079723 True True
```

It's clear that this make no sense, in both cases "is_oov" is True, and it is in the vocabulary. I'm looking for something simple like

```
"andshy" in nlp.vocab = False, "andshy".is_oov = True
"apple" in nlp.vocab = True, "apple".is_oov = False
```

And in the next step, also some word correction method. I can use the spellchecker library, but that's not consistent with the spaCy vocab

This problem appears to be a frequent question, and any suggestions (code) are most welcome.

thanks,

AHe

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: Question is: "how do you do this"? Generalizing the question makes a lot more sense than writing loads of code that does not work (imho).

Comment: I sttill don't know what "this" is, though. What is your question? For tips on how to ask, please refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The question was: "how do I find a word in the spaCy" vocabulary. Sorry for creating the confusion and ambivalence

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: spacy's models do not contain any word lists that are suitable for spelling correction.

Longer answer:

Spacy's `vocab` is not a fixed list of words in a particular language. It is just a cache with lexical information about tokens that have been seen during training and processing. Checking whether a token is in `nlp.vocab` just checks whether a token is in this cache, so it's is not a useful check for spelling correction.

`Token.is_oov` has a more specific meaning that's not obvious from its short description in the docs: it reports whether the model contains some additional lexical information about this token like `Token.prob`. For a small spacy model like `en_core_web_sm` that doesn't contain any probabilities, `is_oov` will be `True` for all tokens by default. The `md` and `lg` models contain lexical information about 1M+ tokens and the word vectors contain 600K+ tokens, but these lists are too large and noisy to be useful for spelling correction.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use the spellchecker (https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/) with some personal hacks. For example, an extensive list of typos that occur in your corpus ...

Answer (score 1):

For spellchecking, you can try spacy_hunspell. 
You can add this to the pipeline.

More info and sample code is here:
https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy_hunspell