# How to Remove non word Characters in NLP

Tags: python, nltk

I am having problem with my regex code

```
round1 = re.sub('\W+', '\n', stringFilter )
```

it doesn't remove non word characters

example
output: s , word , does , au

cleaned output: word , does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a word is an English word with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python)

Comment: You can use nltk library. I don't have it installed now, but it should work.

Comment: @DavideFiocco No , it has same function of regex and corpus words, It still recognize , 's' as English word, even though it is not a word.

Comment: @mulaixi I already using NLTK but what kind of Library did you mean , still trying Corpus.words but I cant still remove the 's' character and other character

Comment: If nltk cannot satisfy I don't know what could satisfy. maybe you can check spacy. you can compare with its vocabulary. @AkioSaito
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495502/how-to-get-all-words-from-spacy-vocab

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something fancy in an NLP pipeline (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/) such as filtering out words that don't have POS tags, lemmatizing, etc. You could also check the corpus in NLTK and if the word is not in it, you can discard it.

Comment: I'm already done in tokenizing and lemmatizing also stopwords and I've been trying the copus.words(), and still getting letters/character like 's'. My code is :   if data in words: print(data) . I'm think about how should I filter or clean this data

Comment: Yes I tried lemmatizing and pos tagging and i don't think it'd work. If that's the case, you can try as @mulaixi suggested. This might help too. Maybe if you could tell us what the problem is with nltk? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290028/removing-non-english-words-from-text-using-python