# Using spacy with archaich/old english words?

Tags: nlp, spacy, vocabulary

I am using **en_core_web_lg** to compare some texts for similarity and I am not getting the expected results.

The issue I guess is that my texts are mostly religious, for example:
"Thus hath it been decreed by Him Who is the Source of Divine inspiration."
"He, verily, is the Expounder, the Wise."
"Whoso layeth claim to a Revelation direct from God, ere the expiration of a full thousand years, such a man is assuredly a lying impostor. "

My question is, is there a way I can check spacy's "dictionary"? Does it include words like "whoso" "layeth" "decreed" or "verily"?

Comment: See this answer:[How to get all words from Spacy vocab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495502/how-to-get-all-words-from-spacy-vocab?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

To check if spaCy knows about individual words you can check `tok.is_oov` ("is out of vocabulary"), where `tok` is a token from a doc.

spaCy is trained on a dataset called [OntoNotes](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2013T19). While that does include some older texts, like the bible, it's mostly relatively recent newspapers and similar sources. The word vectors are trained on Internet text. I would not expect it to work well with documents of the type you are describing, which are very different from what it has seen before.

I would suggest you train custom word vectors on your dataset, which you can then load into spaCy. You could also look at the [HistWords project](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/histwords/).